# Javascript executing function with a string

Tags: javascript

I'm creating a prototype class like so, but I want to call a function using a string as the function name. I found the windowname; example somewhere, but it's not working in my case.

```
function someObj() {

  this.someMethod = function() {
    alert('boo'); 
    name = "someOtherMethod";
    window[name]();
  }

  var someOtherMethod = function() {
    alert('indirect reference');
  }

}
```

Comment: You cannot access local variables via a string containing their name. You can only access object properties this way, so make `someOtherMethod` an object property by either assigning it to `this` or `window` or any other object.

Answer (score 1):

This is because `"someOtherMethod"` is not a member of the `window` object as it defined inside the `someObj` function.

Answer (score 0):

`window` is only for global variables.

You can't access local variables via a string, unles you use `eval`, which is almost always a bad idea.

One alternate way is to use an object. This allows you to look up properties using a string.

```
function someObj() {

  var methods = {};

  methods.someMethod = function() {
    alert('boo'); 
    var name = "someOtherMethod";
    methods[name]();
  }

  methods.someOtherMethod = function() {
    alert('indirect reference');
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

someOtherMethod is hidden from window and exists only in the scope of your prototype.

Try to move it out.

```
function someObj() {
    this.someMethod = function() {
       alert('boo'); 
       name = "someOtherMethod";
       window[name]();
     }
}

var someOtherMethod = function() {
    alert('indirect reference');
}
```

Although it is a bad idea using globals.

Answer (score 0):

Create your own hash of methods:

```
function someObj() {

  this.someMethod = function() {
    alert('boo'); 
    name = "someOtherMethod";
    methods[name]();
  }

  var methods = {
    someOtherMethod : function() {
        alert('indirect reference');
    }
  };
}
```

Your variable is local to your function so it won't be in `window`.  Even if you are working in the global scope, it is better to use your own object than it is to rely on window so you can avoid name collisions.